# Javascript: location.href opens a new window

Tags: javascript, frame

My application is trying to attach a URL to hidden frame by using following syntax.

```
top.frames['main_frame_name'].frames['sub_frame_name'].location.href = URL
```

But when my application executes the above syntax, it opens the URL in a new window instead of attaching it to the hidden frame.

My application and frame application are on different domain.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not referencing your frame correctly, assign an id to frame and set its url by:

```
document.getElementById('myframe').src = URL;
```

This should work;

```
<frameset rows="50%,*" onload="LoadPage();">    
   <frame id="content2"></frame>
   .....
```

Complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadPage(){
    document.getElementById('content1').src = "http://www.google.com";
    document.getElementById('content2').src = "http://www.bing.com";
}
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<frameset rows="50%,*" onload="LoadPage();">    
    <frame src="#" id="content1">    
    <frame src="#" id="content2">                
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not using iframe. My concern is why it is opening a new window.